# Is it possible to import server information from WinScp to Mobaxterm?

Tags: ssh, putty, mobaxterm

Currently I am using WinScp and have set putty to open a terminal session and have saved information regarding the server and credentials in WinScp in folder structure.

But now I want to use Mobaxterm, as I want to do x11 forwarding and use GUI on the terminals.  I am setting up the required properties on the server.  But I need to import my saved information from WinScp to Mobaxterm.  I have not found a way to do that yet.

Is it possible?  If so, how would I do that, without having to individually setup each server with its details on Mobaxterm?

Comment: Thanks.  But since this in on. VDI on a corporate network, unfortunately I don't have access to modify registry.  Is there another way to modify and  import the ini file exported from WinScp?

Comment: Not that I've been able to find in the few minutes I've been looking through MobaXterm. The easiest, if not only, way to do this without PuTTY profiles is to create them from the WinSCP sessions in the Registy: export Registry key `HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Sessions`, find and replace all instances of `Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2` with `SimonTatham\PuTTY`, save the `.reg`, import into the Registry _(even on a corporate VDI, `HKCU` is writeable by the user, else there'd be no saved WinSCP sessions)_, then import those PuTTY profiles into MobaXterm. If this works, I'll create an answer

Comment: Ok, I will try the above.  I actually didn't even try to edit the registry - lest get reported :) - But from your statement, (even on a corporate VDI, HKCU is writeable by the user, else there'd be no saved WinSCP sessions) - it makes sense that I should be able to do it without triggering any security alarms :).  Will try it and let you know.  It maybe later today or next week that I can try, but will definitely respond

Comment: If your user is able to install programs, `HKCU` is writeable by the user, as software installs require `Administrator` privileges because the majority of Windows software writes settings to `HKCU` _(even if software was only allowed to be installed within `%UserProfile%`, it would cripple the majority of software to not be able to write to the Registry AFAIK)_

Comment: Yes, I understand the explanation.  Many a times, they give us a temp password or most of the times we share the screen and  the Helpdesk person puts in the admin password to allow us to install the software.  But like you said, I have been able to save session information for WinScp, so will try to see if I can modify the registry and let you know the outcome.  Thanks

Comment: @JW0914 - I was able to setup the putty sessions the way you explained above.  Even if it showed in the registry entry, it doesn't carry the passwords, but I can reenter them.  Thanks

Comment: I'll writeup an answer this week for it then =]